# Simplest Way to Evaluate Lengthy Integration Equation with Succinct Answer

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, volume

[image]
Recently, I determined the volume of the solid of revolution created by rotating the parabola, $y=ax^2$, about the axis of revolution, $y=bx$, as a function of $a$ and $b$, where both variables are positive, real numbers to be
$$V=\frac{\pi b^5}{30a^3\sqrt{1+b^2}}\tag{1}$$
I proved this [several different ways](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3044474/340652), but I got stuck at the conclusion of my application of the disk method. The final, integrable equation that I derived was
$$V=\int_0^{\frac{b}{a}\sqrt{1+b^2}}\pi\left(-\frac{1}{b}x-\frac{\sqrt{1+b^2}}{2ab^2}+\frac{\sqrt{1+b^2}}{2ab^2}\sqrt{4abx\sqrt{1+b^2}+1}\right)^2dx\tag{2}$$
I happen to know that equation 2 *does* simplify to equation 1 (thank you, [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ssaa0mva1t)). However, I could not think of a way of performing this simplification without a full-blown expansion of the integrand, separation at the plus/minus signs, integration, returning of limits, and simplification, which (I began but did not finish) took a head-exploding amount of care.

In effect, my question is: **What is the most conservative, simplest, best way of evaluating equation 2?** All solutions are welcome, but one that uses relatively elementary calculus concepts would be best (I'm a junior in high school taking AP BC Calculus).

Thanks!

Comment: In your link to "proved this several ways", $b$ was $1.$

Comment: @coffeemath Yes — I just meant that I applied the cone, shell, and disk methods described in that question and its answers. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: Shady Puck-- Just finished getting the rotation volume using Pappus' Theorem [find centroid, get distance $d$ from there to rotation axis, then it's $2\pi d A$ with $A$ the area of rotated region]. I got exactly your formula (1). I'm curious how you set up your disc method-- looks like an involved expression to integrate; I assume discs are perpendicular to rotation axis?

Answer (score 0):

Use computer algebra (e.g., *Mathematica*) which gives a very simple answer:

$$\frac{\pi  b^5}{30 \sqrt{b^2+1}}$$

Comment: Well, yes, that would be very simple. I was asking for a alternate step-by-step solution that did not require the care of a full expansion. BTW, you may want to check your input (as your solution does not match my equation 1).

Comment: @ShadyPuck:  I re-checked my code indeed implements your Eq. (2).  Perhaps you should re-check it.