# Is an equation only a parabola if it is quadratic? Could the graph of $y = x^{1.65}$ be described as parabolic in shape?

Tags: definition, quadratics, conic-sections

If given the equation $y = x^{1.65}$, could it be described as parabolic in shape, or does the equation have to have $x^2$ as its highest degree term?

Comment: 1. Please use mathjax formatting... 2. Shape is different to an actual function. "parabolic" is an adjective, whereas parabola is a function. Do you know what a parabola is? Do you know of its origins?

Comment: Mathematical terminology can be a little fuzzy. For the graph of a function to be a parabola in the conic-section sense, it must have the form "$y=\text{quadratic in $x$}$". However, this doesn't stop people from calling $y=x^3$ a ["cubical parabola"](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicalParabola.html) or $y=x^{3/2}$ a ["semi-cubical parabola"](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SemicubicalParabola.html). Since there's ambiguity in the adjective "parabolic", if you want to describe a vaguely U-shaped graph (such as $y=x^{1.65}$), you might want to opt for "parabola-like".

Comment: While the links @Blue provided do show that such terminology exists: as a professional mathematician, I would never in a million years call those curves "cubical parabolas" or "semi-cubical parabolas". Shudder.

Comment: A semicubic parabola isn't a parabola.  This is similar to how a snub cube isn't a cube, a partial function isn't a function, a truncated icosahedron isn't an icosahedron, or a contravariant functor isn't a functor. The term is a bit archaic, but not completely bizarre.  It's not only mathematical terminology that behaves this way; it's common throughout English.

Answer (score 5):

Not everything u-shaped is a parabola. A parabola has a very specific shape with particular  special properties.

For example, for each parabola there is a point called the "focus" and a line called the "directrix" and each point on the parabola is the same distance from the focus as it is from the directrix. This is similar to the way a circle has a center and every point of the circle is an equal distance from the center.

A shape might look more or less circular, but if it doesn't have a center that is the same distance from each of its points, it isn't a circle.

Curves such as $y=x^{1.65}$, don't have a focus and directrix that behave the way a parabola's do. They might look parabolic, but they are not parabolas.

Note also that an equation may have a parabolic graph even if it isn't obvious.  The answer below of
Vítězslav Štembera says that the equation must have one of two specific forms, but that isn't correct.  Any equation of the form $$Ax^2+2Bxy+Cy^2 +2Dx+2Ey+F=0$$ will have a parabolic graph, if it is non-degenerate and if $AC-B^2 = 0$.  For example, if one takes the parabola $y=x^2$ and rotates it by $45°$ the curve is still a parabola, with equation

$$x^2-2xy+y^2-x\sqrt 2-y\sqrt 2 = 0.$$

(See [Rotate the parabola $y=x^2$ clockwise $45^\circ$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2363075/) for details.)

Comment: Then, could I say that "parabolic" and "quadratic" are interchangeable?

Comment: No, ellipses and hyperbolas are also quadratic.

Answer (score 2):

A parabola is a function of the form $(y-y_0)^2=2p(x-x_0)$ or $(x-x_0)^2=2p(y-y_0)$ i.e. the quadratic term must be always present. $y=x^{1.65}$ is not a parabola.

Comment: Do all parabola functions always have a quadratic term?